# making an onscreen numeric keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, forms

**What i need:** Make a HTML Form that haves a digital numeric keyboard "pin-pad" like a calculator that adds the number to a `<input type=text>` every time you click on the desired number.

**Details:** Supposed to make it possible to enter, for example, a phonenumber, social security number etc. And then, submitting it.

**Problem:** When i click on the `<input id=1>` the `onClick` dont does what i wanted, this value appear's to be always empty or something like that.

**I've tried:** Tried html inline javascript code on the `onClick` event using following without success:

```
<form action="" method="" name="vform">
<input type="text" value="" name="mvar" /><br />
<input type="button" class="fbutton" name="1" value="1" id="1" onClick=”document.vform.mvar.value+='1'” />
</form>
```

How it can be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98Amc/) containing all the numbers (0-9)

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="" name="vform">
<input id=mvar type="text" value="" name="mvar" /><br />
<input type="button" class="fbutton" name="1" value="1" id="1" onClick=addNumber(this); />
</form>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
function addNumber(element){
  $('#mvar').val($('#mvar').val()+element.value);
}
```

JavaScript native:

```
function addNumber(element){
  document.getElementById('mvar').value = document.getElementById('mvar').value+element.value;
}
```

Comment: you're right. i dont know if the op are using jQuery right? i'll add native javascript solution

Comment: this worked absolutely beautifull ;)

Answer (score 0):

For that you might require to use a third party plugin.

Otherwise you would need to write the whole code yourself. However, your code won't show up the numeric keyboard on screen, since on Desktop almost all of the users have their own keyboard, so users don't need a virtual keyboard. Browser won't bother showing a keyboard either!

If you want to show a keyboard on screen and input data from there, you need to write the code, or search for **numeric on screen keyboard javascript**.

Answer (score 0):

There is basically not much wrong with your code...except the type of surronding quotes matters....
It looks like you have 'opening' and 'closing' type of quotes around your onClick attribute. If you make them simple like the others your code works.

```
<form action="" method="" name="vform">
<input type="text" value="" name="mvar" /><br />
<input type="button" class="fbutton" 
       name="1" value="1" id="1" 
       onClick="document.vform.mvar.value+='1'"/>
</form>
```

with a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2mx7/)